# Почему Date() неправильно работает с timestamp?

Tags: php

Простой пример:

```
echo date('G:i', '1419960480');
```

где `1419960480` это дата: `2014.12.30, 21:28:00`

Результат: **9:28**

Comment: Всё правильно работает :)

> echo date('H:i:s d.m.Y', '1419960480');

Результат:

>17:28:00 30.12.2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, неправильно установлена временная зона.

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT-4"); 
echo date('G:i', '1419960480'); 
?>
```